# R: Subscripted assignments not overwriting values, or changing all values (halfway figured out)

Tags: r, boolean, variable-assignment, overwrite, subscript

I have had a problem in my R code that comes up from time to time, where I will try to overwrite values of a variable using a subscripted assignment, and some/all of the values do not get overwritten. (I have since figured out half of the problem, but the second half of the question still applies.)

Here is a simplified example of the code, which compares two variables to see which one is bigger, then finds places where they are equal and sets the "is bigger" variable to -1 to indicate that neither is bigger.

```
a <- rep(0:2,96)
b <- rep(0:3,72)
dataset <- data.frame(cbind(a,b))
dim(dataset) # Show dimensions

> [1] 288   2

# Add a few random NAs
dataset$a[15] <- NA
dataset$b[27] <- NA
dataset$a_bigger <- (dataset$a > dataset$b)
dataset$b_bigger <- (dataset$b > dataset$a)
table(dataset[,c('a_bigger','b_bigger')],useNA='ifany')

>        b_bigger
>a_bigger FALSE TRUE <NA>
>   FALSE    70  144    0
>   TRUE     72    0    0
>   <NA>      0    0    2

dataset$same <- (dataset$a == dataset$b) # Find values where they are the same and neither is bigger
table(dataset$same,useNA='ifany') # Show that there are NAs in dataset$same.

> FALSE  TRUE  <NA>
>  216    70     2

dataset$same[is.na(dataset$a) | is.na(dataset$b)] <- 0 # Fix the NAs. A and B can't be the same if one of them is NA.
table(dataset$same,useNA='ifany') # Show that there are no longer NAs

>   0   1
> 218  70

dataset$a_bigger[dataset$same] <- -1
dataset$b_bigger[dataset$same] <- -1
table(dataset[,c('a_bigger','b_bigger')],useNA='ifany') # Wait, there should be 70 changed, not 1...?

>         b_bigger
> a_bigger  -1   0   1 <NA>
>    -1     1   0   0    0
>    0      0  69 144    0
>    1      0  72   0    0
>    <NA>   0   0   0    2
```

Up to this point, I have figured out what happened. Setting a few values of "same" to 0 changed it from logical true/false to 0/1, and then when I used it to index another variable, the "1s" were taken to mean "overwrite the first row" instead of as logical trues.

This had me confused since in other contexts R *will* treat 0/1 as equivalent to true/false (in fact, if I rewrite the assignment line as `dataset$a_bigger[dataset$same & dataset$same] <- -1`, that works) but at least I can understand what's happening now.

But I still don't understand why it does this:

```
dataset$even_weirder[dataset$same] <- -1 # But now if I do the assignment on a column/variable that's not initialized...
table(dataset[,'even_weirder'],useNA='ifany') # They all change!!!

>  -1
> 288
```

If it really thinks that when I write `dataset$somevar[dataset$same]` I'm referring to position 0 (which it ignores) and position 1 (which it overwrites over and over), then when I do it with an uninitialized column why does it assign -1 to every row instead of assigning it to the first row and leaving the rest NA?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is basically

```
class(dataset$same)
#[1] "numeric"
```

which is not logical but binary i.e. 0 and 1

```
head(dataset$same)
#[1] 1 1 1 0 0 0
```

Instead it should be

```
as.logical(dataset$same)
```

Because the assignment is haappening at index position 1 i.e. the value -1 is getting updated on the 1st element and not anywhere else

```
dataset$a_bigger[as.logical(dataset$same)] <- -1
dataset$b_bigger[as.logical(dataset$same)] <- -1

table(dataset[,c('a_bigger','b_bigger')],useNA='ifany')
#        b_bigger
#a_bigger  -1   0   1 <NA>
#    -1    70   0   0    0   #### 70 is showing up now
#    0      0   0 144    0
#    1      0  72   0    0
#    <NA>   0   0   0    2
```

---

Regarding the 'even_weider', it is created on the fly and because of that the first element when it gets assigned to `-1`, gets recycled to the entire length of the column

```
dataset$even_weirder[dataset$same]
#NULL
dataset$even_weirder[dataset$same] <- -1
sum(dataset$same)
#[1] 70
table(dataset[,'even_weirder'],useNA='ifany')

# -1 
#288 
dataset$even_weirder
#  [1] -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
# [39] -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
# [77] -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
#[115] -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
#[153] -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
#[191] -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
#[229] -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
#[267] -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
```

Comment: Thanks! I understand that part now, but what I haven't figured out is the bottom part with the uninitialized column where instead of thinking the "1" refers to row 1, it writes to every row.I understand that 0/1 aren't functioning as logical here, but they don't seem to be functioning as numeric indexes either (at least in the second part) and I'm curious what it's doing!

Comment: @TiredSquirrel Consider this `v1 <- c(1,  2, 3, 4, 5); i1 <- c(1, 0, 1, 0, 1); v1[i1] <- -1`

Comment: The value changed only `v1#
[1] -1  2  3  4  5` because 1 is. only positioin it is mentioned and 0 is not considered as R indexing starts from 1

Comment: In this part, it seems to think that my 0s and 1s refer to rows other than row 1: ```dataset$even_weirder[dataset$same] <- -1``` and ```table(dataset[,'even_weirder'],useNA='ifany')``` shows 288 instances of -1, instead of one -1 and 287 NAs.